# How do sessions work?

Tags: security, session-cookies

I have a script set up to create sessions for when user is logged in.

The users permission level is then grabbed along with some other fields from the users table based on the username and password session upon login.

I have then set the users permission and users id as sessions.

I then use the users id to select stuff from other tables based on their id.

Is this secure? can someone force a session change and somehow get data from another user? or is it ok to set lots of data ( apart from password ) into a session varable?

Cheers and i hope it makes sense .. just to recap:

Can i set the user id of a logged in user into a session cookie and is there a way that someone could change the cookie and try to view somoene else data by guessing their user id?

Cheers
John

Answer (score 0):

Security rule number 1 - do not implement your own authentication and session management schemes. Try to always rely on your platform/framework standard implementation.

In your scenario session cookie is untrusted data (i.e. an attacker can modify it on the way back to the server). If your session IDs are easy to guess (e.g. incremental integers) then it is trivial to change this ID and become another user in your system (session hijacking).

If you have to use your own mechanism consider the following:
1. Track IP addresses associated with your sessions. Think what you want to do if you see a request from a different IP address.
2. Use hard to guess session IDs/tokens. E.g. don't use integers - use guids. If you have to use session ID as an integer then introduce some sort of GUID associated with this session ID and store it on the server end along with the session ID and on the client end in the cookie.
These 2 values should always match - otherwise thie request is not genuine.

Comment: On the one hand you propagate not to use a custom authentication or session management scheme, but on the other hand you suggest things that I would call a custom implementation. Like the [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) (quite a general term) which can have quite little entropy (v1) and much entropy (v4).